# Unix ls files within a certain time range

Tags: unix, timestamp

I'm trying to find files that have dates within a specific time range (like the last 2 months).

How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `find` command has an -ls argument, which would provide the functionality you desire:

```
find /path -mtime -60 -ls
```

Good luck.

Comment: I noticed that -60 works, but 60 doesn't. Why is that? Since the manual says "-mtime n: File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago." Shouldn't it be 60 (positive)?